# Steps to build full stack application iOS

Tags: ios, mobile

What is the basic approach for mobile app development and how to choose technologies specifically for iOS?
What I mean is, what should the first step be; for ex.

1.UI development

2.UI testing

3.Backend

and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I would say learn Swift and Xcode for iOS development. This learning leads to both front and back ends aspects, including testings and debugging. It leads also to connecting with third party platforms (remote data base etc).